# Number of faces after cutting cubes from the corners of a cube

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

Given a 5cm sided cube.

If a 1cm cube is cut from each corner, how many faces will the new shape have?

Comment: From one corner when you remove a cube, you add three new faces.

Comment: Thanks Dustin. So essentially, the new shape will have 78 faces?  It did have six faces to start with, then as you say, removing a cube will add 3 additional faces in each corner...so thats 12 additional faces for each each of the original sixes faces = 72 additional. Plus the six original faces. Makes 78 in total. Is that correct please? Thank you

Comment: sorry - just seen your explanation. Thank you

Comment: You cut out 8 smaller cubes so $8\times 3 = 24$ plus the original 6 is 30

Answer (score 1):

The new shape will still have a face for each of the 6 faces of the original cube, plus three faces for each of the 8 cubes cut out, for a total of 30 faces.

Answer (score 0):

$$
6 \text{(regular faces)} + 3\times 8 \text{(cut faces on each vertex)} = 30
$$